# How do I show events in Full Calendar with Google Calendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

How do I show full day events that have been inputted into my google calendar to display through Full Calendar? I have got the calendar up on my webpage but it is not showing anything. My client wants to be able to input full day bookings on google calendar and it will automatically update itself on full calendar.

Is this some type of PHP that I need to implement?

here is my code:-

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='fullcalendar-2.2.5/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>   
<script src='fullcalendar-2.2.5/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar-master/dist/gcal.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
enter: 'title',
right: 'month,agendaWeek, agendaDay'},
defaultDate: '2015-1-1',
editable: false,
googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDU6qxbGV0VpsX44iaQFSfDT3ozrr2WlRA',
events: 
{
googleCalendarId: 'bktfu2utt8bmf9g39kjn8bpvpc@group.calendar.google.com',
className: 'gcal-event',
allDay: true,

}

});
});
```

Comment: ClassName,allDay are properties of Event Object. An "event source" can be simple array, an event-generating function that you define, a URL to a json feed, or a Google Calendar feed. So, include the properties in simple array.Check this link http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/

Comment: I have no idea how to implement this within my already placed code? The website is confusing me. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: events: [
{
googleCalendarId: 'bktfu2utt8bmf9g39kjn8bpvpc@group.calendar.google.com',
className: 'gcal-event',
allDay: true,

}]  try this

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I already have that bit of code in my script(?)

Comment: Yes you have that but include that in array. That is what I did..

Comment: I'm sorry it still does not work :( I wish I could understand how to retrieve Full day events from my Google calendar onto my Fullcalendar but it just does not want to show anything

Comment: Interesting as I have just found this! Not sure what It means as I have followed all the instructions:- Google Calendar API: Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.

Comment: Ah! Just figured it!! In the JS I added this :eventSources: [
    'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/bktfu2utt8bmf9g39kjn8bpvpc%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic'
    ] works brilliant! :D Here is the link to see what I have done: http://jsbin.com/bapazi/2/

Comment: Great :) good that everything is working fine now!!